# Can't find SQL view in Access 2010 while using .mdb?

Tags: vb6

I can't find the **SQL view** in **Access 2010** when I open the **.mdb**(access 97 format) database file **created with Visual Basic 6 inbuilt database.**

It works fine when I open a **new** database document ** (.accdb) ** in Access 2010, but that version of the access file (.accdb) is not supported in **Visual Basics 6.0**.
I know it's weird that I still use VB6 but I have no other go since my university only allows to use VB6.
So, is there any way I can solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "can't find SQL view". You can open mdb files in Access 2010 and edit queries using both the query designer and also the SQL editor.

It is also possible to open accdb files using VB6. Here is the proper connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

Taken from:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/standard-security/

Comment: I know that .mdb files created by access 2000 and above has 'SQL view' but the access 97 version of .mdb doesn't seem to support 'SQL view'[writing query in SQL] as it is disabled in create tab.

Comment: So, i recommend you convert the Access 97 to the 2010 format ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-HA010341552.aspx) and connect to the accdb file using the connection string in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Luke Wage for your support!